# What is the proper approach to insert into multiple tables at once?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-insert

For example I have a table called `product_list`, which holds a list of products:

```
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+--+
| id | name  | weight(g) | type        |  |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+--+
| 1  | Shirt | 157       | Clothes     |  |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+--+
| 2  | Ring  | 53        | Accessories |  |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+--+
| 3  | Pants | 202       | Clothes     |  |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+--+
```

and a table called `product_price`:

```
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
| price_id | id | name  | price  |  |
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
| 1        | 1  | Shirt | 99.00  |  |
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
| 2        | 2  | Ring  | 149.00 |  |
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
| 3        | 3  | Pants | 119.00 |  |
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
```

If I insert 1 row of data into `product_list`, part of the data (such as `product_id` & `product name`) should also be inserted in another table like `product_price` which holds the price for all products (new products would have 0 or NULL values for their price). Eg:

`product_list`:

```
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+--+
| id | name   | weight(g) | type        |  |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+--+
| 1  | Shirt  | 157       | Clothes     |  |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+--+
| 2  | Ring   | 53        | Accessories |  |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+--+
| 3  | Pants  | 202       | Clothes     |  |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+--+
| 4  | Shirt2 | 175       | Clothes     |  |
+----+--------+-----------+-------------+--+
```

`product_price`:

```
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
| price_id | id | name  | price  |  |
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
| 1        | 1  | Shirt | 99.00  |  |
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
| 2        | 2  | Ring  | 149.00 |  |
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
| 3        | 3  | Pants | 119.00 |  |
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
| 4        | 4  | Shirt2| 0.00   |  |
+----------+----+-------+--------+--+
```

My question here is the method in approaching this. What is the proper way (in a professional manner) would an experienced person approach this matter?

These are 2 approaches I have in mind:

#### 1 - Using triggers to insert into the other tables like `product_price`,etc whenever I insert a product data into `product_list`

#### 2 - Using a function (stored procedure) like `product_add` to add a new product into each tables.

Which method is better? Or if there a better suggestion, then I'd like to know about it. Thanks in advance.

TLDR: Should I use `Triggers` or instead use `Stored Procedures`, which is better? Or you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use CTEs:

```
with pl as (
      insert into product_list(name, weight, type)
          select . . .
          returning *
     )
insert into product_price(id, price)
     select id, NULL
     from pl;
```

Note:  You shouldn't repeat the `name` column in the `product_list` and `product_price` table.  It should only be in the list table.

Comment: I have a couple of questions. 1. If I'm using an admin dashboard to enter new products (client side) into the database, this CTEs you mentioned, would you call a `stored procedure` or just run this code or using `triggers`?  2. Why the `name` column shouldn't be repeated if I wanted to use easily for name reference? If I created a view, I wouldn't have to even join tables for the name. Or I wouldnt even need to select 2 separate views, I could just select 1 view,  wouldn't that make it easier job?